# GetLine to compare strings works once then the compare doesn't work after

Tags: c++, getline

```
while((addRemove == "R" || addRemove == "r") && continueLoop == true)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < choreVector.size(); i++)
    {
        if(choreVector[i] != "")
        {
            cout << choreVector[i] << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter value to add to remove from the list" << endl;
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, userValue);

    cout << endl;

    for(int j = 0; j < choreVector.size(); j++)
    {
        if(userValue == choreVector[j])
        {
            choreVector.erase(choreVector.begin() + j);
        }
    }

    cout << "Would you like to remove another item from the list(y/n)" << endl;
    getline(cin, userValue);
    cout << endl;

    if(userValue == "n" || userValue == "N")
    {
        continueLoop = false;
    }

}
```

So my problem is that I have a list of chores in a vector with spaces with items like:
'Take out garbage'
'Walk the Dog'

My problem is that the user has the option to remove from the vector from Keyboard input so i've been using getline for cin input. 
The Getline works flawlessly on the first run to remove any element but fails on the second run through and won't remove an element after removing the first. I have cin.ignore before the GetLine which to my knowledge cleared the buffer and would ignore any data from previous cin.

Probably something stupid im overlooking but if anyone could help that would be great.

Comment: `cin.ignore();` doesn't "clear the buffer". It consumes and discards *one* character from the pending input stream, aborting that effort if the `eof` state is tripped, and, if that is the case, subsequent read requests without an interceding `clear()` will automatically fail. *Never* assume your input operations succeed. You're *destined* to assume wrong sooner or later (and usually at the most inopportune of times, like when a prof, or worse, a paying customer, is running your code).

Comment: remove `cin.ignore()`.

Comment: @jackw11111 I have tried that but then the read won't remove from the vector at all

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the issue seems to lie with your IDE. A typical IDE will have some sort of "Output" or "Messages" tab that is configured to show the output of the window, because it has been auto-configured to pipe the output from the compiler to this window. Depending on your IDE, they may or may not also support input in this window. At worst, input can be very buggy, half working, half broken. I generally *assume* any IDE I use does not support input in that window, and will either compile the program manually on the command-line / terminal, or I know code::blocks and Visual Studio open a console window, which has support for user input and output, and will make sure to use that.

Comment: Whenever I don't use a cin.ignore() statement before my getline, the getline is ignored and the program skips past it. Thats why I had it there in the first place

Comment: Repl.it. Ill try it in Vis studio and see if that works

Comment: can you try it with command-line if you can; general rule-of-thumb I use is that if I know my program will need input, I compile on command-line.